# how to force to default.aspx instead of www.domain.com

Tags: asp.net, redirect

OK. I'm having a ridiculous problem. I'm trying to use URL rewrite to redirection from www.domain.com to www.domain.com/default.aspx.

I thought by setting default.aspx as the default document it would automatically drop the user there. But for some reason it still comes up www.domain.com.

The reason I want it to go to www.domain.com/default.aspx is that the login control on the page doesn't seem to want to work when it is just the www.domain.com. But of course if I type in the www.domain.com/default.aspx then the login works fine. The login control doesnt seem to post at all if it is www.domain.com. Anyway, I'm trying to avoid troubleshooting why the login control is not firing and just force it to land on default.aspx anytime someone tries to go to www.domain.com. I'm using IIS7. Any ideas here?

Comment: when you enter www.domain.com which document is loaded?

Comment: default.aspx. Except that it doesn't show in the url. the Url stays at www.domain.com.

Comment: I thought the default (no pun intended) was that if you set a default start page, IIS will find it and dump you there with the url looking like this www.domain.com\default.aspx. So I'm not sure if something changed in IIS7 or if I am just the worst asp .net programmer of all time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anwer has to do with a breaking change in ASP.NET 4. Answer was that the form action was empty `action=""` when on extensionless root url. but if on that same page, but had the name of the page in the url (blahblah.com/default.aspx) the action gets filled in. the easy fix for me was to put `Me.Form.Action = "Default.aspx"` on the page load of the home page. problem fixed.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a ton of hair pulling and swearing. I'll need to find something else to do with the rest of my day now :)

Answer (score 5):

You could add something like this to your Default.aspx code behind (in your Page_Load method):

```
if (Request.Url.LocalPath == "/")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Note that the default document setting normally allows that page to be displayed under www.domain.com/ *and* www.domain.com/default.aspx (it doesn't do any redirecting for you).

Comment: Dang it. That didn't work. OK. Here's some other info. I'm forcing the entire site to HTTPS using rewrite in the web.config.

Comment: <rewrite>
    
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

Comment: In addition, my forms section looks like this: <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="timmy" path="/" loginUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" defaultUrl ="default.aspx">
   </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>

Comment: Ok. Closing this. Seem to have a larger problem. One of my sites works just fine from the root "/" for the login. The other one does not. Must be something else going on.

Comment: Dude!! I found out the answer for this one and it really sucked. It has to do with a breaking change in asp .net 4. Answer was that the form action was empty action="" when on extensionless root url. but if on that same page, but had the name of the page in the url (blahblah.com/default.aspx) the action gets filled in. the easy fix for me was to put Me.Form.Action = "Default.aspx" on the page load of the home page. problem fixed.